# Django tutorial 1 not showing polls

Tags: django, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I am taking a test Driven Development course for python (which is awesome) Obeythetestinggoat and so my Django needs work. So I'm taking the Djangoproject.com course and I get all the code entered and the server runs but the polls won't change.

The home page http://127.0.0.1:8000 shows

"It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page."

Which is great but it won't show the polls or the admin buttons and I've run out of ideas on how to redirect it but not sure the problem.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

I'm rather proud that I figured out the server and other areas but I just don't know what I am missing to get the page to show the polls.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: You need to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls instead of / . Also check that you have added the polls app to INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ . Otherwise if you want put your default polls page on the home page like you intended to do in http://127.0.0.1:8000/

you could do this in your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment but...

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls
* gives an error * 

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
* loads just fine... ?

Comment: are you sure you have it right inside of yours  polls/views.py -> def index(request): ? what is your error log in console ?

Answer (score 0):

`http://127.0.0.1:8000` is the main page of your preoject, but in the urls, you define (with regex) how to manage requests to  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`. You should visit those URLs.

Comment: Yes the polls pages "should" show but it doesn't load.System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 02, 2017 - 01:15:35
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /polls

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request)
 return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")

# Create your views here.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `urls.py` at the wrong place made by the `django-admin startproject mysite` command.

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── asgi.py
│   .
│   .
│   │
│   ├── urls.py       <-- right place
│   └── wsgi.py
├── polls
│   .
│   .
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── urls.py           <-- wrong place
```

If you forget to *remove* it, and keep it, while creating the right one at the right place, it prevents the rules of the right one to be applied.